# Omitting parameter names in C

Tags: c, file-io

So I'm going over some code for file I/O in C and am confused on one line of a makeshift cat function.

I'm mainly confused on the line in main:

```
void filecopy(FILE *, FILE *);
```

We are not specifying the names of the files to be passed in for ifp and ofp so I'm not sure what this line is doing.

```
/* filecopy: copy file ifp to ofp */
void filecopy(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp) {

    int c; 

    while((c = getc(ifp)) != EOF){
        putc(c, ofp); 
    }
}


/* cat: concatenate files, version 1*/
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *fp;
    void filecopy(FILE *, FILE *);

    if(argc == 1){ /*no args: copy standard input */
        filecopy(stdin, stdout);
    }else{
        while(--argc > 0){
            if((fp = fopen(*++argv, "r")) == NULL){
                printf("cat: can't open %s\n", *argv);
                return 1; 
            } else{
                filecopy(fp, stdout);
                fclose(fp); 
            }
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: regarding: `fopen(*++argv, "r"))`  be very careful about the operator precedence in C.  I.E.  this expression: `*++argv`  is very 'iffy'

Comment: it's calling the function to run in your main program

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
void filecopy(FILE *, FILE *);
```

Is a **function declaration** and is used to allow other code to call a function.  It specifies that a function exists with a given name and a given number of parameters of known types.  The names of those parameters are not needed in order to call the function.  They are only needed when you **define** a function, i.e. when you specify the body of a function.

Note that in this example the declaration is not needed because the function is fully defined earlier in the file.

Comment: To make it completely explicit: a function declaration does not *call* the function, it just declares how the function name should be interpreted within the scope of the declaration -- in this case, as the name of a function that accepts two arguments of type `FILE *` and returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687119/dbush), the line:

```
void filecopy(FILE *, FILE *);
```

is a function declaration.  It can also be called a function prototype.

It isn't needed in this case, if your code is arranged as you have shown it.  If the *filecopy()* function were located after *main()* or in another file, you would need to have the declaration above main() somewhere.

If *filecopy()* were in another file, the prototype would probably be in an include file (.h) to be included in your main.c file.